# Sort list of number and array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

So I create this list of tuples where each tuple consists of an int and an array.

```
a = ((1, array([1,2,3])), (4, array([1,3,3])), (2, array([1,3,2])))
```

I want to sort the list so that the list is ordered from increasing int order.

ie.

```
a = ((1, array([1,2,3])), (2, array([1,3,2])), (4, array([1,3,3])))
```

I tried using

```
a.sort()
```

which from the article I was reading should have sorted it how I want to but it returned the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Read the error...see what it says. It's pretty clear. If it isn't, google it. THEN ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly specify `key` function argument, so that only the first item; to make the `int` object is used as sort key:

```
>>> a = [(1, array([1,2,3])), (2, array([1,3,2])), (4, array([1,3,3]))]
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> a
[(1, array([1, 2, 3])), (2, array([1, 3, 2])), (4, array([1, 3, 3]))]
```

Comment: Just a note: the author's 'list' is actually a tuple, which has no `sort` attribute.

Comment: @timgeb, The question title mentions `list`.

Comment: @falsetru Just change your answer to use the `sorted` builtin instead since it works for any container or iterable type.

Comment: @falsetru yes, I just figured the author does not know the difference to a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `sorted` to sort by the first element using a lambda expression:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = ((1, array([1,2,3])), (4, array([1,3,3])), (2, array([1,3,2])))
>>> a = tuple(sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0]))
>>> a
((1, array([1, 2, 3])), (2, array([1, 3, 2])), (4, array([1, 3, 3]))
```

Note that `a` is a tuple and thus immutable. That's why I'm casting the return value of `sorted` to a tuple and reassign `a`.